# How to fix MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

hello I am a beginner developer and I was following a tutorial on udemy about mongoose, unfortunately the tutorial is outdated so I had to write it with documentation.
this is my code:

```
//require the Mongoose package (after running >npm i mongoose in Hyper to install it)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
//connect to MongoDB by specifying port to access MongoDB server
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
 
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/FruitsDB');
  }
 

    //create a SCHEMA that sets out the fields each document will have and their datatypes
    const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
        name: String,
        rating: Number,
        review: String
    })
     
    //create a MODEL
    const Fruit = new mongoose.model ("Fruit", fruitSchema)
     
    //create a DOCUMENT
    const fruit = new Fruit ({
        name: "Apple",
        rating: 7,
        review: "Great!"
    })
     
    //save the document
    fruit.save()
     
    //**CHALLENGE: Set up a people database with one document and two fields**//
    //create a SCHEMA
    const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      age: Number,
    });
     
    //create a MODEL
    const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
     
    //create a DOCUMENT
    const person = new Person({
      name: "John",
      age: 37
    });
     
    //Save it
    person.save();
```

but console only gives me an error back saying:

```
 MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

I have being trying to fix it for hours, if you could help that would be great

Comment: Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you are not connected to the database. Make sure that you are indeed connected to the database before trying to perform any operation.